# Dynamically load chunks in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

We load files dynamically i.e., we don't know which files will be loaded until runtime. At the same, for faster loading, we'd like to put related files in the same chunk.

How can I do that with webpack?

This is what we have and it's failing with a 404 error (1.1.bundle.js not found)

This is what webpack.config looks like:

```
entry: {
   main: //...,
   related_files: [ //should create chunk for file1 and file2?
     './file1.js',
     './file2.js'
   ]
},
```

This is what the code to dynamically load the files looks like:

```
var dynamicFileName = //...

require.ensure([], function (require) {
  //should dynamically load the chunk containing dynamicFileName? 
  //fails with 'file1.js' or 'file2.js' 
  var modImpl = require(dynamicFileName);
  //...
});
```

Update 1: the error message is caused by not configuring `output.publicPath`. However, I never created `1.1.bundle.js`. It seems to be ignoring the entry point.

Update 2: even after fixing `output.publicPath`, it's unable to load a dynamically generated filename. So it seems that webpack cannot handle this.

Answer (score -1):

By default, webpack tries to bundle all the code in a single file. If you're using code from file1.js/file2.js in `main` entry point, webpack will bundle contents of all the files in `main.js`, and second entry point `related_files` will output only file1/file2 contents.

Webpack handles this situation by using `CommonsChunkPlugin`, your config must look like this:

```js
entry: {
   main: //...,
   related_files: ['./file1.js','./file2.js']
},
plugins: [
   new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('related_files', 'related_files.js')
]
```

Second part of the question is that webpack parses `require` statement, and outputs `1.1.bundle.js` - the dynamic module, that can be loaded with require in the code. In your case, `dynamicFileName = 'related_files'`, not file1/file2.

Please see http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code

Comment: Require('related_files') is exactly what I do NOT want to do. Is there a way to make require('file1') work dynamically?

Comment: In this case you need to remove second entry point and require needed modules in code like `require('./file1.js')`.

Comment: If I remove the entry point then either everything gets put in one bundle or I lose control over the bundle for the related files (these need to go in the same bundle)